# How to make a click on TableViewCell open a new view and keep data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

So I've added a UITableView in a UIViewController. I also subclassed its TableViewCells to look like this :

[image: http://d339vfjsz5zott.cloudfront.net/70_UITableView_Display/UITableView_Preview_Part-2.png]

Now I just want to know how I can click on the cells to open a new view with another TableView containing a selection of options, and to write the selected option instead of the "This is row : %d" line. (everything is embedded in a NavigationController)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UItableview Delegate

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You will get click event. In that you can use indexPath.row for retriving string from your data source array (which contains data you shown in cell.) on which user has clicked. Now you can open (push)new view controller using navigation.

Pass the indexPath.row or particular string to your next view controller so that you can get which one is get selected.